# Unable to view apache default page from outside local network

Tags: apache2, lamp

This is driving me crazy. I've installed ubuntu server with LAMP. I have the firewall forwarding port 80 to my web server and have verified that the port is open. I can see the default page from any of my local systems just fine but when attempt to browse from my phone over 3g I get nothing.

Interestingly if I try and add a non existent page, like /nothing, to the domain name or public ip I get an apache error telling me "Not Found". I'm an ubuntu newbie but it looks like I can access the web server its just not configured right somehow.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect from your phone you have to connect to your external IP.

If you have access so you can login to the router you can see your external IP. You will have to forward port 80 on your router using "port forwarding" so that it forwards  any connection to your external IP to to port 80 on the IP of the server.

As for the new files you will have to change their permissions using `chmod` and `chown`

This guide should get you started on the right foot
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/serverguide.pdf